# Diagnosing intermittent internet connection issues

Tags: networking, router, dns, internet

Using XFinity with 150Mbps download speed. I've been having inconsistent issues with web browsing resulting in timeouts. One minute, the internet is zippy, the next, time out errors. Trying to run the test at SpeedTest.net fails...sometimes giving an error, like latency test error.

The issues are on multiple browsers, from a laptop using Windows 10, and a direct ethernet connection to the router.

I've had Xfinity/Comcast, come out to check all equipment and run tests, which all passed according to them.

Using GlassWire desktop app to view network traffic from this laptop...nothing unusual.

Did a tracert and getting some time outs there...not sure if that is typical or maybe the DNS I'm using is the weak link?

[image]

Modem log and stats
[image]

[image]

Comment: Chad, these errors in your log indicate a problem at the street level. T3 based time out should have been seen by the visiting tech.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Disconnect all splitters in the house for troubleshooting. Make sure that the modem has a straight line to the incomming aerial or underground cable coming to your house.

If you can no longer recreate the issue you have a problem with your inside wiring, or splitters in the house.

T3 timeouts usually indicate a problem at the street level, and usually has to do with water in a repeater box, a source of interference on the feeder line etc.

When you call them again, make sure to mention you disconnected all splitters and set-top boxes. (Creating a home-run to the modem) And mention the range timeouts and specifically T3 time out errors in the modem.